# Replacing H1 text with a logo image

Tags: html, css

I want to have my site logo displayed as an H1 element on my page with HTML and CSS. Also, I need the image to be made smaller with CSS to be in keeping with my page. How can I go about doing this?

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance,
Callum

Comment: logo is an image and H1 is a styling for text. Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your question is? The basic idea is `<h1><img src="..."></h1>` although the question is how much sense it makes, seeing as it's a semantic element designed to contain text content.

Comment: So you have the same H1 on every page? Is that wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how you can do:

html:

```
<h1 class="logo">My Company</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1.logo{
  display:block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(images/logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  text-indent: -20000px;
}
```

Comment: well, you can't set image width/height when you set that as background image, however, you can set the image size if you have any tool like photoshop or you can use an online service like: http://www.resizeyourimage.com/ or http://www.picresize.com/

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<h1 class="logo">My Logo Text for SEO</h1>
```

CSS:

```
.logo { background:url(path/to/image.gif) 0 0 no-repeat; display:block; height:50px; overflow:hidden; text-decoration:none; text-indent:-9999em; width:50px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background of the element to an image in CSS:

```
h1
{
    background-image: url('Images/Logo.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

It would probably better to assign an id to the `h1` tag and reference the element by id in the css, or use a class if it can apply to more than one `h1` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1 style="background-image:url('file.jpg')"></h1>
```

Comment: There should be something which sets the size of your `h1` element, otherwise it will be too small.